# PHP upload multiple images

Tags: php, directory, image-uploading, directory-structure

This code used to work and now I can't figure why it won't upload, I don't receive errors, I also don't receive any echo's or var_dumps back at all, it's simply like the button only refreshes the page. (Just for clarification there is alot more code doing alot of stuff, but this is the cause of my issue as I isolated it into another project with below code, which gave me the same results).

All it is meant to be doing is creating a folder named by the "ItemName", then it should be moving the images into that new named folder.

Thank you in advance, this problem has been hindering me for a few days now...

HTML PAGE

```
<form id="newsell" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<input type="text" class="css-input" name="ItemName"  value="">

<input name="file[]" type="file" id="file" multiple />

<input type="submit" name="Upload" class="css-input1" value="Upload">

<?php
 if ($_POST['Upload']) {
 require_once("random.php"); 

}
?>
```

random.php

```
$MyLocation = "MyName";  // this comes from db, for this case just hardcode
$ItemName1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ItemName");
$ItemName = strip_tags($ItemName1);
$parentDir = "C:/wamp/www/HOME/uploadimages/".$MyLocation;   
echo "Does it exist...." . $parentDir . "/" . $ItemName;
if(!is_dir($parentDir)) { // Check if the parent directory is a directory
echo "Apologies, something has gone wrong.";
RandError();   // POPUP
die();
}

    if(!is_writable($parentDir)) { // Check if the parent directory is writeable
 echo "Apologies, something has gone wrong.";
        RandError();   // POPUP
        die();
    }
    if(mkdir($parentDir . "/" . $ItemName) === false) { // Create the directory
       echo "File apparently exists...." . $parentDir . "/" . $ItemName;
        ExistingSaleName();  // POPUP
        die();
    }
//  die('Created directory successfully'); // Success point
echo "AFTER INSERTION";
    movefiles();
}



function movefiles() {
$MyLocation = "MyName";
echo "In movefiles";
$ItemName1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ItemName"]);
$ItemName = strip_tags($ItemName1);
extract($_POST);
if (extract($_POST) === null) { // trying to fault find here, but never returns anyway due to some kind of bug as at one point it was returning a null value
echo "PROBLEM...";
}
$error=array();
$extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png");
$res = ("C:/wamp/www/HOME/uploadimages/". $MyLocation. "/" .  $ItemName);
foreach($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
    $file_tmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    if (!(($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]    ["type"][$key] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] ==     "image/jpg"))) {
        die("Only the .jpg / .jpeg / .png file's were uploaded.");
    } else {
        echo "SHIT";
    }
var_dump($file_tmp);
   $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $count;
    //check if file exist       
        if (!file_exists($res . "/" . $file_name)) {
            sleep(2);           
            if (isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key])) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], $res);
                ++$count;
                if ($count >=5) {
                    // go_to(); // This goes onto the next function
                    die ("First 5 images are uploaded, <br/> 5 images     maximum.");
                }
            } else {
                echo "It exited HERE...";
            }
        } else {
            ExistingSaleName();
             die();
        }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create simple code to upload multiple images. Changes it yours.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    $desired_dir="user_data";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
```

}
?>

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
```